# how do getByteTimeDomain/FrequencyData() method work

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm trying to develop pitch-detector using JavaScript Web Audio API. By googling, I've knew we perceive pitch by frequency so I found getByteFrequencyData() method. But I don't know how to use it correctly.

**example.js**

```
function draw() {
 var img = new Image();
 img.src="foo.jpg";
 img.onload = function() {
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
     var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     var raster = imgData.data;
     for (var i=0;i<raster.length;i++) {
          if (i % 4 != 3) {
               raster[i] = 255 - raster[i];
          }
     }
     ctx.putImageData(imgData,0, 0);
 }
}
```

As we see above, getImageData() returns very obvious, easy-to-access data. In contrast, What does a parameter *"buffer"* of getByteFrequencyData() save/represent/mean? How does it represent audio frequency data? How can I manipulate/handle it and develop my own program using these methods?

Thanks.

Comment: Uh.... What is the relation between this Image and Canvas code with regard to Audio analysis?

Comment: sorry for my writing skills ToT.. image datas are represented by red,green,blue and alpha channel value. but what do buffer elements obtained by getByteFrequencyData() stand for?

Comment: Yes I know about Canvas API and what an ImageData is, I also know a little bit about WebAudioAPI, and the getByteFrequencyData and getByteTimeDomain. But what I really know is that they are not the same API whatsoever! It's just like if you said *I found out about hammers being good for nails, now I'd like to know how to use it for my flowers.*

Comment: Source code written in these question doesn't relate my program. It's just for my question, but it seems to fail to explain. Okay! Ignore and forget Canvas API, ImageData, etc.. I'm wondering what buffer saves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spec entry for [getByteFrequencyData](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-analysernode-getbytefrequencydata) tells you exactly what it is.  The analyser node determines the frequency content in a set of bins where the value of each bin is the magnitude of that frequency component.  `getByteFrequencyData` just converts that dB and then scales the values to the range of 0 to 255.

I generally recommend people to use `getFloatFrequencyData()` first because I think it's a bit easier to understand without having to deal with the scaling.

Comment: and what are the frequencies in each bin?

Comment: If there are N bins and the sampling frequency is Fs, the k'th bin (starting from 0) has the frequency k/N*(Fs/2), more or less.